# How do I search for a combination of values in a "dict" object in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to update/append a list of dictionary items based on another list.

**ParentList**

```
{'date': '2019-03-07', 'start_time': '2019-03-07 10:08:21', 'duration': '5'}     
{'date': '2019-03-07', 'start_time': '2019-03-07 10:14:43', 'duration': '15'}
{'date': '2019-03-07', 'start_time': '2019-03-07 10:31:22', 'duration': '13'}
```

**NewList**

```
{'date': '2019-03-07', 'start_time': '2019-03-07 10:08:21', 'duration': '5'}     
{'date': '2019-03-07', 'start_time': '2019-03-07 10:14:43', 'duration': '15'}
{'date': '2019-03-09', 'start_time': '2019-03-09 10:31:22', 'duration': '13'}
{'date': '2019-03-10', 'start_time': '2019-03-10 10:31:22', 'duration': '13'}
{'date': '2019-03-11', 'start_time': '2019-03-11 10:31:22', 'duration': '13'}
{'date': '2019-03-12', 'start_time': '2019-03-12 10:31:22', 'duration': '13'}
```

I want to update the **ParentList** with the new items in the **NewList**. As you can see, the first 2 items from the latter are repeated in the former. So I want to add only the last 4 items(from **NewList**) into the **ParentList**.

The simple method would be to iterate through each **NewList** item and check if it already exists in the **ParentList**.

**Code**

```
for newItem in NewList:
    bln_item_exists = False
    for parentItem in ParentList:
        if dict(newItem).get("date") == dict(parentItem).get("date") and dict(newItem).get("start_time") == dict(parentItem).get("start_time"):
            bln_item_exists = True
            break
    if not bln_item_exists:
        items_to_append.append(newItem)
```

I am worried that as my DB size increases, the performance would be hit, is there a more efficient way to do the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these type of operations I would recommend using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(ParentList)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(NewList)
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2])
df3.drop_duplicates(subset=['date', 'start_time'], inplace=True, keep='last')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of hash checksums of each item that is present in »parent list«:

```
import hashlib;
import json;

hashes = {}
parent_list = [ ... ]

def createHash (item):
  hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
  hash_md5.update(json.dumps(item))
  return hash_md5..hexdigest()

for item in parent_list:
  hashes[createHash(item)] = true


def appendList(child_list):
  for item in child_list:
    hash = createHash(item)

    if hash is not in hashes:
      hashes[hash] = true
      parent_list.append(item)
```

The basic Idea is: use a hash of the json serialized object to test for equality, this way all properties are checked implicitly.

Comment: Thanks for that solution @philipp. I felt the Pandas solution was much more simpler for my use case.